# How to properly use array subscripting notation?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to read correctly this :

```
*(strarray[i]+j)=0;
```

I was understanding something like :

```
strarray[i][++j] = 0;
```

or

```
strarray[i][++j] = '\0';
```

but is not exactly the same. How could it be written correctly as an array subscripting notation?

Comment: Why did you change `+j` to `++j`?

Comment: `++j` and `+j` have nothing to do with each other. `++j` CHANGES `j` itself while `+j` simply adds j's value to whatever comes before in the code.

Comment: What is the type of `strarray`? Is it `char**`?

Comment: yes, Nikita, it is char**. The answer posted below solved my confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the postfix array subscripting notation,

```
*(strarray[i]+j)=0;
```

will be

```
 strarray[i][j]=0;
```

Quoting the `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.2.1, *Array subscripting*

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]` is a subscripted
>   designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator `[]`
>   is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. [...]

In your case, you can consider `E1` as `strarray[i]` and `E2` as `j`.

Comment: Thanks Sourav, it works, that little + was disturbing. i will check more about Array subscripting.

Comment: Nice reference to C11.

Comment: Nice. And the general rule here is: when we say a[i] we always mean *(a + i).